# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET for only javascript files

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-config

I have a simple static webpage (HTML CSS JS) hosted on a DigitalOcean droplet using nginx. Everything worked as expected until last night when it the javascript files stopped being served. When I access the website, the HTML and CSS files load fine, but the javascript files get a connection reset error (first discovered on Chrome, but same issue on Safari). The error logs in /var/logs/nginx only contain one line:

2021/01/13 05:57:56 [notice] 1428#1428: signal process started

which I believe isn't relevant...

I only have one webpage being served and the configuration for my nginx is completely default. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Found out why. Sorry, but this actually wasn't an nginx issue at all. I believe that somehow, my router blocked http js traffic so getting https setup for my site fixed everything.